# Are there any method to prevent downloading all dependencies by Gradle after copying android project to other folder?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Every time I copy my Android Studio project to another folder, when I try to open the project the Android Studio and Gradle build system act such that the project is imported for the very first time and Android Studio starts to download and fetch whole dependencies again.
Something like this:

[image]
I was wondering if I'm doing something in the wrong order or if it is the usual behavior of the Android studio?

I was looking for a method to avoid all downloads again and again by each copy/rename of the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some steps you can follow to prevent Gradle from downloading all dependencies again:

1. You can use `Gradle's Offline Mode` to force your project to use dependencies that are already downloaded.
2. You can `Copy Gradle Cache Folder` to the same location on the new folder. This cache is usually located under `.gradle/caches`.
3. Ensure that you're using the `Gradle Wrapper` in your project. This ensures that the same Gradle version is used across different environments. The wrapper scripts `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` and the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` and `gradle-wrapper.properties` files should be part of your project repository.